# Lua accessing values inside a 2D array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, lua

It seems like this should be a simple thing. I have converted the following json structure to a lua table but I am having trouble trying to access the values inside of the array. I have looked through many questions and the internet in general and none of the examples I have tried work.

Here is the json that was converted to a lua table using cjson.decode

```
[{
    "user": "user_1",
    "password": "something",
    "id": "35",
    "message": "message 1"
},
{
    "user": "user_2",
    "password": "something",
    "id": "5c",
    "message": "message 2"
},
{
    "user": "user_3",
    "password": "something",
    "id": "7e",
    "message": "message 3"
},
{
    "user": "user_3",
    "password": "something",
    "id": "6f",
    "message": "message 4"
}]
```

I then try to access the variable like this:

```
ngx.say(users[0]["user"]);
```

However that does not work. I want to iterate the array and get out the user, password, id, and message at each index of the array but first I wanted to just see how to access the value of user at index 0 .. which should be user_1. I know this is a n00b question but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua tables start at index 1 by default.

Comment: yeah, thought of that and tried ngx.say(users[1]["user"]); but still no joy

Comment: @JoelParker it would help if you'd provide an error message instead of just saying it does not work ;)

Comment: this is for the lua module in nginx and it just crashes, no error given

Comment: @JoelParker users[1]["user"] should work given that your json was loaded and decoded correctly. Add more code to your question.

Comment: I am going to dump the table created by cjson and see if it looks correct. If it doesn't I will share what cjson is creating during a decode operation

Comment: ok, I tried this with a standard table:  local users = {};

 users[1]["user"] = "user_1"; and it gives me the error: input:3: attempt to index a nil value (field '?')

Comment: In that case, `users` is an empty table, so it won't work. (`users[1]` is nil.)